# Multiplying what's pointed to by pointers

Tags: c, pointers

`Pointer1` points to `5`.

`Pointer2` points to `3`.

I want to multiply 5*3, but I only have the pointers. How would I do this in C?

Also, what does `uint32_t *pointer` mean when:

`pointer[2] = {1, 2};`

Comment: I don't actually think I understand what you want. Also, please don't ask two questions in one question.

Comment: (For example, what's a "segment"? what are you "multiplying"? what are you trying to point to in memory?)

Comment: Your question is very vague, need more contextual info. "Creating buffer to multiply numvers" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: nneonneo: Sorry my second question was answered below so I will keep it in the question so future people don't get confused. I will try to keep it to 1 question a post in the future. gerrytan and nneonneo: I have updated the question. Please let me know if it is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know what is so hard for the answerers to understand about this question. It is obviously about dereferencing pointers.

This is how you display the contents of the pointer that it is pointing to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

        int num1 = 5;
        int num2 = 3;
        int* num1_ptr = &num1;
        int* num2_ptr - &num2;
        int sum = *num1_ptr * *num2_ptr;
        printf("%d\n", sum);
        return 0;

}
```

*num1_ptr and *num2_ptr takes your pointers and references what the contents of that memory address.

Comment: In my case, I was wondering how to prevent `*a * *b` to be interpreted as `*a **b`. The `sum` line confirmed what I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer the first half of your question without more information, but `uint32_t* pointer` is simply a pointer to an unsigned 32-bit integer value (`unsigned int` and `uint32_t` are usually equivalent types, depending on your compiler).

If I see a declaration that simply reads `uint32_t* pointer` without more information I'm going to assume it's a pointer to a single value, and that using the indexing operator `[n]` on such a pointer is basically overflowing the single-element-sized buffer. However if the pointer is assigned the result from an array or buffer function (e.g. `malloc`, `calloc`, etc) then using the indexing operator is fine, however I would prefer to see `uint32_t pointer[]` used as the declaration as it makes it much easier to determine the developer's intent.

Answer (score 0):

`uint32_t *pointer` is just a pointer with garbage value unless you point it to something.

```
pointer[0] = 1;
pointer[1] = 2;
```

is only valid if you have earlier pointed it to some array of type `uint32_t` with atleast size two or to a block containing `uint32_t`s defined using `malloc` as follows:

`uint32_t *pointer;`

```
pointer = (uint32_t*)malloc(sizeof(int*SIZE); //SIZE > 2 here
```

or

`uint32_t array[10];`

```
pointer = & array[0]; // also, pointer = array; would also work.
```

Comment: How are you pointing to bits in a no? Are you trying to do an AND of two nos?

Comment: `uint32_t pointer[2] = {1, 2};`? `pointer` is *not* a pointer here, it's an array. In some expressions, arrays are converted to pointers to their first element.

Comment: Thank you immibis. I was wondering: what if pointer is an array with more than 32 integer bits? How can uint32_t *pointer be a pointer to an 32-plus-bit integer value?

Comment: Is it a 64 bit machine? You can typecast your pointer to point it to anything you want. For eg if you typecast it to char* then you will be able to access the number in units of 8 bits.

Comment: "I was wondering: what if pointer is an array..." - pointers are not arrays, so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I meant the variable called "pointer", lol. But it's okay, tarun answered my question.

Comment: PSA: Don't cast malloc. `(type*)malloc(...)` is a useless idiom for C++ compatibility in C, which is itself useless because C and C++ are different and incompatible languages all the way down to their (weak and strong, respectively) type systems. C++ has `new`, so it doesn't need `*alloc`. And C has a weak type system, so it doesn't need `(type*)`. No matter what, you are generating polyglot code that violates the DRY principle. Which is inefficient. You should always compile C code with the tools that were made to compile C, i.e. a compliant C compiler.

Comment: Also, I don't even think that will work. You have `sizeof(int*SIZE)`, which is a syntax error. Assuming that `SIZE` is a macro symbolizing an integer, you'll get `error: expected ‘)’ before numeric constant`. Remember two things: 1. `sizeof` is an unary operator, not a function; 2. The proper usage of `sizeof` is `sizeof foo` for objects, or `sizeof (type)` for types. In your case, you should have written `sizeof (int) * SIZE`. I personally prefer to leave a space between `sizeof` and its operand to make it clear that it's not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(void)
{
    int variableA = 5;
    int variableB = 3;
    int* ptr1  = &variableA;  // Pointer1 points to 5.
    int* ptr2  = &variableB;  // Pointer2 points to 3.

    int answer;

    answer = (*ptr1) * (*ptr2);  // I want to multiply 5*3, but I only have the pointers. 
    // Answer gets set to [value stored at ptr1(5)] MultipliedBy [value stored at ptr2(3)]
}
```

Your misconception is that pointers do not refer to *values*, such as `5` and `3`.
pointers refer to *variables*, such as `variableA` and `variableB`; those variables have values which can be accessed and changed via the pointer.

But the pointer only refers to the variable, not directly to the value behind it.